# Iterate over all structs in a module

Tags: c++, types, llvm, type-systems, llvm-ir

I'm writing a ModulePass and I need to analyze **every** struct defined in the given module.

I understand that identified structs with a name are inserted in the ValueSymbolTable, but how can I iterate over all the other structs (identified with no name and literal structs)?

Answer (score 6):

The correct way of doing this is:

```
#include "llvm/IR/TypeFinder.h"

llvm::TypeFinder StructTypes;
StructTypes.run(M, true);

for (auto *STy : StructTypes)
  STy->dump();
```

You should not use any private/opaque types (like LLVMContextImpl) whose headers are not published.

Answer (score 2):

The `LLVMContextImpl` instance associated with your current context should have two data structures, one containing all the identified structs in the current context (whether or not they have an explicit name), and the other containing all the literal structs.

To get the `LLVMContextImpl` instance:

```
Module& M = ...
LLVMContextImpl* C = M.getContext().pImpl;
```

For the identified structs:

```
C->NamedStructTypes
```

For the literal structs:

```
C->AnonStructTypes
```

Both return iterable types (`StringMap` for the first, `DenseMap` for the second), allowing you to iterate over them and get all the types out.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool runOnModule(Module &M) override
{
    for(auto *S : M.getIdentifiedStructTypes())
    {
        S->dump();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Oak's answer, here's a more complete code example:

```
Module& M = ...
LLVMContextImpl* C = M.getContext().pImpl;
for (StringMap<StructType *>::iterator i = C->NamedStructTypes.begin(); i != C->NamedStructTypes.end(); ++i)
{
    StructType *t = i->getValue();
    t->dump(); fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

LLVMContextImpl.h, being the header for a private implementation, isn't one of LLVM's public headers. You can get it from the LLVM source code — either copy it from there into your header search path or, for quick & dirty testing, do:

```
#include "/path/to/llvm/src/lib/VMCore/LLVMContextImpl.h"
```